# SyntaxError on the beginning of the block

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

Can someone explain why this is wrong?

```
object = Special::MyObject.new 'string' { "a block" }
```

I get a `SyntaxError` on

```
.. { "a ...
    ^
```

It expects a keyword_end

If I remove the block everything works fine

Comment: @Batkins This won't be a block, this will be a broken hash

Comment: Ahh, sorry misunderstood the question.  To be fair he didn't exactly elaborate on what he was trying to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use brace block (`{ ... }`) with methods with no parentheses. You can use `do ... end` or add `(` ... `)`.

```
object = Special::MyObject.new('string') { "a block" }

object = Special::MyObject.new 'string' do
  "a block"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
object = Special::MyObject.new('string') { "a block" }
```